# adding multiple variables to a filter

Tags: r, dplyr

trying to figure out how to filter by multiple variables. my data set has multiple variables (age, sex, race, etc) and I want to filter by at least three of them:

```
# pulling libraries
library('dplyr')
library('ggplot2')

# reading the data
data <- read.csv('week2_dataset.csv')

#looking at the data
data

#viewing the data in a more pretty way
View(data)

#selecting variables
data %>%
  select (variable, group, total, insured) %>%
  filter (variable == 'race')
```

The problem comes in when I try to filter by more than one, what's the best way to select multiple variables when filtering? Thank you!

Here is the requested data:

```
structure(list(variable = c("age", "age", "age", "age", "age", 
"age"), group = c("<6", "6-18", "19-25", "26-34", "35-44", "45-54"
), total = c(23521379L, 54060901L, 29854012L, 39733565L, 40515666L, 
41040536L), insured = c(22519138L, 51046307L, 25585349L, 33566727L, 
35106537L, 36591730L), uninsured = c(1002241L, 3014594L, 4268663L, 
6166838L, 5409129L, 4448806L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please run `dput(head(data))` and provide the output as part of your question to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: It sounds like your data is organized with multiple values possible in the variable named "variable." Perhaps you want `filter(variable %in% c("race", "age"))`?

Comment: use `filter(variable %in% c('race', 'age'))`

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, you can use the `%in%` operator here to try to pull multiple arguments from a single variable. I show how to not only do that, but also how to include multiple variables in case you want to do more than just one operation. Here is with one variable as mentioned in the comments:

```
#### Filter For Groups in One Var ####
df %>% 
  filter(group %in% c("6-18", 
                      "19-25"))
```

Giving you two rows:

```
 variable group    total  insured uninsured
1      age  6-18 54060901 51046307   3014594
2      age 19-25 29854012 25585349   4268663
```

Here is how you can do it with multiple variables:

```
#### Filter Multiple Vars ####
df %>% 
  filter(group %in% c("6-18", 
                      "19-25"),
         insured > 2000000,
         uninsured < 4000000)
```

Giving you now one row:

```
  variable group    total  insured uninsured
1      age  6-18 54060901 51046307   3014594
```